# C# - Linq : Unable to create a constant value of type Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using this linq query for login

```
var login = context.Person_Login
                   .Where(c => c.Username == username && c.Password == password)
                   .DefaultIfEmpty(new Person_Login({Id = -1})
                   .First();
```

but in execution  throw this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'MyProject.MyModels.Person_Login'. Only primitive types or enumeration
>   types are supported in this context.

Comment: Using `context.Person_Login.Create()` throws a similar exception. Entity Framework won't create a new entity within a LINQ query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception message is quite descriptive.

`DefaultIfEmpty(new Person_Login({Id = -1})`

is not supported in Linq to Entities.

You can use the following instead

```
var login = context.Person_Login
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Username == username && c.Password == password)
    ?? new Person_Login {Id = -1};
```

Note that `DefaultIfEmpty` method is used mainly for performing LINQ left outer joins.

Comment: thank it's work but why, i use this statement in Entity5 and work just fine but now  throw this eception

Comment: @Milad Well, newer versions are not always required to be backward compatible.

Comment: Unfortunately, compiler doesn't help a lot with `IQueryable<T>` queries. All the unsupported things can be caught only at runtime. So, testing, testing :)

Comment: problem is i wrote all my Controls in this way  and now changing to this, Lesson Learn!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var login = context.Person_Login
                   .Where(c => c.Username == username &&
                   c.Password ==password)                       
                   .FirstOrDefault();
login = (login != null) ? login : (new Person_Login({Id = -1}));
```

Comment: Thanks, is going to work it's to similar @ivan-stove and i prefer his answer, Less Coding

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var login = context.Person_Login
                   .Where(c => c.Username == username && c.Password == password)
                   .FirstOrDefault(new Person_Login({Id = -1});
```

Comment: thank, but No, FirsOrDefault can not get this input vs throw erro in this line

Answer (score 0):

```
var login = context.Person_Login
.Any(c => c.Username == username && c.Password == password) ? 
    context.Person_Login.First(c => c.Username == username && c.Password == password) :
     new Person_Login({Id = -1});
```